# How to do a task only once for logged in users

Tags: users, actions, init

I want to do a task only once after an user has visited my site. I am currently doing like this:

```
function my_task(){
    //do my tasks
}
add_action('init', 'my_task');
```

I am doing this from a plugin.
This actually loads **my_task()** function every time users load any page of wordpress. But I only want to load it once for each user for each session. Once they close the browser, and come back again, I want it to load again only for once till they exit.

How can I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but I've recently addressed a similar problem by using cookies.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_93797_cookie' ); 
function wpse_93797_cookie() {
  if ( !isset ( $_COOKIE['wpse_93797_cookie_name'] ) ) {
    // Do your stuff.

    // Set your cookie so we don't do stuff the next time around.
    // Note that 0 makes the cookie expire at the end of the user's browser session.
    setcookie( 'wpse_93797_cookie_name', 'some-value-we-did-stuff-btw', 0, '/' );   
  }
}
```

[Manual for cookies on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Also maybe helpful:

[How can i set , get and destroy cookies in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress)